# how to send token to url in c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, session, url, token

using `System.Net.WebClient` and `DownloadString` the URL contents gives me a token. the server uses this token as "https://address/page?token=AAABBBXXX".
by using this code

```
string contents;
string token;
string url = @"https://address/login";
var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
contents = wc.DownloadString(url);
token = contents.Substring(contents.IndexOf("page.public.pageToken = '") + "page.public.pageToken = '".Length, 32);
url = "https://address/page?token=" + token;
**contents = wc.DownloadString(url);** //error error error !!!!
```

I can get token value from page content but how to send this token and validate my request? last line causes server error timeout! shall I save token value in any session? how do it in windows application?

Comment: What the actual exception is can you post it? try to copy this post in try catch block and then look for the actual exception that is being thrown by code

Answer (score 1):

```
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient()
{
    string WebURL = @"http://www.mywebsite.com/somefolder/somepage";

    NameValueCollection param = new NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "token", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890" }
    };

    object WebResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(wc.UploadValues(WebURL, "GET", param));
}
```

correct me if i am wrong, but you said "send", which might be equal to "upload".

that above code would be equal to a browser processing a link @ `http://www.mywebsite.com/somefolder/somepage?token=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890`

Comment: this works if I know token already. but I call some url and get token and then call another url from same site and send token with `GET`. in web state it is done by SESSION variables but in form apps i don't know how to save like that. WebClient object does not save SESSION variable `token`?

Comment: are you working with `GET` or `POST` in getting a token from the said link ?

Comment: i am using GET. first call link `A` from website and get `token` then call link `B` from same website and send `token` with `GET`. but WebClient object does not save session and server does not accept token.